Master's in Germany for an applicant from India who has two Bachelor's degrees
I have completed a Bachelor's degree in History (Honors) from Delhi University, and I am currently pursuing a second Bachelor's degree in Computer Applications (BCA) from Amity University Online. My BCA program started in 2023 and is expected to finish by 2026.
I am interested in applying for a Master's degree in Germany after completing my BCA. Would having two different Bachelor's degrees (one in History and one in Computer Applications) affect my eligibility or chances of being accepted into a Master's program in Germany? Specifically, I'm curious about how German universities view applicants with diverse academic backgrounds and whether both degrees will be considered during the admission process.
Additionally, are there any specific challenges or advantages I should be aware of when applying for a Master's program in Germany with this academic profile?

Germany is a federal state and universities have additional autonomies. I am looking at the Masters in Informatik of Hamburg University. You need to have a Bachelors in a closely related field with minimum number of courses in computer science and mathematics, that correspond to the curriculum of the bachelor's degree at Hamburg University. If you almost fulfill these requirements, you can get a conditional admission, at least as a German student.
Your application might receive additional scrutiny because your BCA degree is online. Also, this seems to be a three year degree and you might not have enough courses in either Computer Science or in Mathematics, though the B.Sc. in Germany is three years as a rule. I would worry about having enough classes in Mathematics.
You would also have to have prove an excellent command of German.
In general, recognition of a "foreign degree" is a non-trivial procedure.
This is only the result of reading the requirements for one German university. You need to go through a few of them and see where you are. It occurs to me that you might be able to make up a small deficit by taking courses at my alma mater, the FernUniversität Hagen. (You could even get a degree there while staying in India).
